# How can I make the arrow into a straight line?

Tags: css

I have some css that is part of a bigger project, and 
I would like the arrow to be a straight line.

Here is the CSS.

```
/** panel arrows **/
.timeline li .timeline-panel:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 26px;
  right: -15px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-top: 15px solid transparent;
  border-left: 15px solid #ccc;
  border-right: 0 solid #FF0000;
  border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
  content: " ";
}

.timeline li .timeline-panel:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 27px;
  right: -14px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-top: 14px solid transparent;
  border-left: 14px solid #FF0000;
  border-right: 0 solid #FF0000;
  border-bottom: 14px solid transparent;
  content: " ";
}
```

I also made an http://jsfiddle.net/y4g27b6s/

Comment: I can't tell from the fiddle how you want the result to look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you mean because your question was extremely unclear?

```
.timeline li .timeline-panel:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 26px;
  right: -15px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-top: 1px solid #FF0000;
  border-left: 10px solid #FF0000;
  border-right: 10px solid #FF0000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FF0000;
  content: " ";
}

.timeline li .timeline-panel:after {
 position: absolute;
  top: 26px;
  right: -15px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-top: 1px solid #FF0000;
  border-left: 10px solid #FF0000;
  border-right: 10px solid #FF0000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FF0000;
  content: " ";
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y4g27b6s/1/